# Cyclic group order 15

Tags: group-theory

Let G be a cyclic group of order 15. Why must G contain at least 2 elements of order 3?

Is it to do with Cauchy's theorem? Then once we know that it has one, the inverse of this element has order 3 as well?

Answer (score 1):

Let $G$ be generated by $a$, i.e. $\langle a \rangle = G$.

Then, $a^5$ and $a^{10}$ are both elements of order $3$(, and there is no other).

Comment: That makes so much sense- thanks!